# How to correctly use Django Slippers in templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Django Slippers is a new template rendering library. I started using Django Slippers recently and I am very confused with some things. I am trying to render a template but I keep having this error. I don't know where this error is from:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load slippers %}


{% block content %}
  
{% #card title='video game' name='name1' %}
  <span>Hii</span>
{% /card %}

{% endblock %}
```

This is my template. I have this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 241, in wrapper
    if any(
       ^^^^
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I don't understand why I'm having this issue and Django Slippers is fairly new so there is no help online. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have an update, and it has to do with the Django version. Apparently, I'm using the 4.2 version but django slippers work for the lower version instead